# Neural network learning only when single output node is used

Tags: java, neural-network, output

I've been working on a neural network that learns how to do basic multiplication: 1*0, 1*1, 1*2, ... 1*9. I map the above values to two inputs: 1, 0.0; 1, 0.1 ; 1, 0.2; ... 1, 0.9. My initial idea was to use 10 output nodes such that: for inputs 1, 0.5 you would have the outputs 0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0. So, the output node with the position indicated by the second input value should have the value 1.

The main problem is that the network won't learn like that:

```
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.0; calc. output: 0 outputs: [0.94048536, 0.75189143, 0.90448654, 0.84964263, 0.92710346, 0.9205896, 0.9166514, 0.9185999, 0.795943, 0.81590974]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.1; calc. output: 0 outputs: [0.94168836, 0.6586949, 0.88201404, 0.7996992, 0.9125166, 0.9040279, 0.8969305, 0.9007438, 0.72104955, 0.74867773]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.2; calc. output: 1 outputs: [0.59459364, 0.626284, 0.5367963, 0.37009117, 0.5410054, 0.5135251, 0.45009533, 0.5312547, 0.3342563, 0.34696856]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.3; calc. output: 2 outputs: [0.30291027, 0.3520163, 0.69235265, 0.24563757, 0.3124528, 0.24798703, 0.2366348, 0.36106965, 0.24116497, 0.23960127]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.4; calc. output: 3 outputs: [0.14643292, 0.14488237, 0.20816484, 0.7138216, 0.14679325, 0.14442608, 0.14322245, 0.14553475, 0.14529803, 0.14485884]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.5; calc. output: 4 outputs: [0.111300476, 0.11054926, 0.12775657, 0.17022455, 0.517143, 0.11048156, 0.10996126, 0.11087219, 0.11077163, 0.11069376]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.6; calc. output: 5 outputs: [0.091701485, 0.091235556, 0.100025855, 0.113540664, 0.079323635, 0.40588042, 0.090913385, 0.09137165, 0.09132192, 0.09130932]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.7; calc. output: 6 outputs: [0.07876296, 0.07844582, 0.08373607, 0.090930566, 0.07063774, 0.075600885, 0.33777672, 0.07862692, 0.07864317, 0.078639545]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.8; calc. output: 7 outputs: [0.069422215, 0.069256335, 0.07245374, 0.07753391, 0.06380278, 0.06732645, 0.078282, 0.29474476, 0.06972643, 0.06970157]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.9; calc. output: 8 outputs: [0.062300637, 0.062199928, 0.06432947, 0.06806077, 0.05821499, 0.0608177, 0.06845653, 0.07952615, 0.26235205, 0.06267065]
MSE avg. slope: 29.733704


Run: 71656; input: 1.0 and 0.0; calc. output: 9 outputs: [0.010279003, 0.02896637, 0.043276917, 0.053958114, 0.0630066, 0.071741395, 0.08170587, 0.095196836, 0.1174955, 0.2159805]
Run: 71656; input: 1.0 and 0.1; calc. output: 9 outputs: [0.0103677455, 0.028743964, 0.042845763, 0.053532414, 0.06259656, 0.07137894, 0.08135815, 0.09476117, 0.11689092, 0.21750201]
Run: 71656; input: 1.0 and 0.2; calc. output: 9 outputs: [0.010355595, 0.031080922, 0.042447396, 0.052969296, 0.06184091, 0.07039538, 0.08002176, 0.092763215, 0.113420375, 0.20233525]
Run: 71656; input: 1.0 and 0.3; calc. output: 9 outputs: [0.010345513, 0.030882018, 0.051248915, 0.052218866, 0.060734913, 0.06885447, 0.07785396, 0.08951517, 0.10782931, 0.1783656]
Run: 71656; input: 1.0 and 0.4; calc. output: 9 outputs: [0.010335368, 0.030656299, 0.050334506, 0.07143845, 0.059316203, 0.06685822, 0.07505537, 0.085399605, 0.100998335, 0.15348937]
Run: 71656; input: 1.0 and 0.5; calc. output: 9 outputs: [0.0103242155, 0.030395139, 0.049267467, 0.06860315, 0.09226974, 0.06452598, 0.071837306, 0.08079469, 0.09371151, 0.13176109]
Run: 71656; input: 1.0 and 0.6; calc. output: 9 outputs: [0.010311599, 0.030096399, 0.048070885, 0.0655594, 0.0853547, 0.114023075, 0.06839305, 0.076017134, 0.08652923, 0.114047475]
Run: 71656; input: 1.0 and 0.7; calc. output: 6 outputs: [0.010297287, 0.02976092, 0.046773087, 0.062431496, 0.0788379, 0.09977333, 0.13687406, 0.07129724, 0.079778984, 0.09988401]
Run: 71656; input: 1.0 and 0.8; calc. output: 7 outputs: [0.010281161, 0.029391168, 0.045403145, 0.05931676, 0.07286063, 0.088408194, 0.11082662, 0.16097555, 0.07361035, 0.088530056]
Run: 71656; input: 1.0 and 0.9; calc. output: 8 outputs: [0.010263171, 0.028990407, 0.04398821, 0.05628488, 0.067463, 0.07921742, 0.09398328, 0.117479034, 0.18689476, 0.07932637]
MSE avg. slope: 20.656487
```

The MSE avg. slope is an indicator of how far we're from the expected result. The calc. output is a function that detects the max value from the 9 output nodes. The outputs are the 9 nodes' actual outputs.

The interesting part is that if I convert my network to one with a single output neuron, so that: 1*0.3 expects just 0.3, then everything works:

```
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.0; calc. output: 0.7 outputs: [0.73059195]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.1; calc. output: 0.7 outputs: [0.6943731]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.2; calc. output: 0.6 outputs: [0.59459066]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.3; calc. output: 0.5 outputs: [0.47402766]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.4; calc. output: 0.4 outputs: [0.40803587]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.5; calc. output: 0.4 outputs: [0.40256947]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.6; calc. output: 0.4 outputs: [0.4390238]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.7; calc. output: 0.5 outputs: [0.51111925]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.8; calc. output: 0.6 outputs: [0.61495394]
Run: 0; input: 1.0 and 0.9; calc. output: 0.7 outputs: [0.7283057]
MSE avg. slope: 6.411294


Run: 1059; input: 1.0 and 0.0; calc. output: 0.0 outputs: [0.07036249]
Run: 1059; input: 1.0 and 0.1; calc. output: 0.1 outputs: [0.12572113]
Run: 1059; input: 1.0 and 0.2; calc. output: 0.2 outputs: [0.20584798]
Run: 1059; input: 1.0 and 0.3; calc. output: 0.3 outputs: [0.30965355]
Run: 1059; input: 1.0 and 0.4; calc. output: 0.4 outputs: [0.42281863]
Run: 1059; input: 1.0 and 0.5; calc. output: 0.5 outputs: [0.52661973]
Run: 1059; input: 1.0 and 0.6; calc. output: 0.6 outputs: [0.61548316]
Run: 1059; input: 1.0 and 0.7; calc. output: 0.7 outputs: [0.6934447]
Run: 1059; input: 1.0 and 0.8; calc. output: 0.8 outputs: [0.76261413]
Run: 1059; input: 1.0 and 0.9; calc. output: 0.8 outputs: [0.82081395]
MSE avg. slope: 1.1993817
```

Does anyone have any idea what the reason might be? Will be eagerly awaiting any suggestions. A great day to you all!

Comment: some code might help, maybe there is the problem

Comment: https://ufile.io/0vx6l                       
This is the one with multiple outputs.

Comment: https://ufile.io/toc0t   This is the one that works, but with a single output. Thank you for the hasty reply Baumer!

Comment: There's a lot of redundant code in there since I kept trying different things as time went by. I hope it's manageable.

Comment: please include the code in your question. lots of people don't follow links

Comment: Please try the link. It's just an archive with my NetBeans project. If you still think it's risky for you, I'll post the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found the issue: in the code I wasn't resetting the value of the average slope after each epoch, but I was still using it as a learning rate.

This lead to drastic weight shifts on each step. That eventually lead to convergence towards 0, which meant that the average error was pretty low. The average slope was lower than the initial value, but still huge.

Once I correctly reset it, it would accurately reflect when the network was fit enough (which is anywhere < 0.711).

I got a lot of help from:
[Strange convergence in simple Neural Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741187/strange-convergence-in-simple-neural-network)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gvq9sUHPgrc (giant_neural_network
 slope of cost func. video)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIeHLnjs5U8 (3Blue1Brown Backpropagation video)