# Neural Network Overestimating output of handwritten digits

Tags: c++, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

So, I try to create my own neural network. Something really simple.

My input is the MNIST database of handwritten digits.
Input: 28*28 neurons (Images).
Output: 10 neurons (0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9).
So my network is as follow: 28*28 -> 15 -> 10.

The problem remains in my estimated output. Indeed, it seems I have a gradient explosion.

The output given by my network is here: https://pastebin.com/EFpBGAZd

As you can see, the first estimated output is wrong. So my network adjust the weights thanks to the backpropagation. But It doesn't seems to updates the weights correctly. Indeed the estimated output is too high compared to the second highest value. 
So the first estimated output keeps being the best estimated output for the following training (13 in my example).

My backpropagation code:

```
VOID BP(NETWORK &Network, double Target[OUTPUT_NEURONS]) {
double DeltaETotalOut = 0;
double DeltaOutNet = 0;
double DeltaErrorNet = 0;
double DeltaETotalWeight = 0;
double Error = 0;
double ErrorTotal = 0;
double OutputUpdatedWeights[OUTPUT_NEURONS*HIDDEN_NEURONS] = { 0 };
unsigned int _indexOutput = 0;
double fNetworkError = 0;

//Calculate Error
for (int i = 0; i < OUTPUT_NEURONS; i++) {
    fNetworkError += 0.5*pow(Target[i] - Network.OLayer.Cell[i].Output, 2); 
}
Network.Error = fNetworkError;


//Output Neurons
for (int i = 0; i < OUTPUT_NEURONS; i++) {
    DeltaETotalOut = -(Target[i] - Network.OLayer.Cell[i].Output); 
    DeltaOutNet = ActivateSigmoidPrime(Network.OLayer.Cell[i].Output); 

    for (int j = 0; j < HIDDEN_NEURONS; j++) {
        OutputUpdatedWeights[_indexOutput] = Network.OLayer.Cell[i].Weight[j] - 0.5 * DeltaOutNet*DeltaETotalOut* Network.HLayer.Cell[j].Output;
        _indexOutput++;
    }
}

//Hidden Neurons
for (int i = 0; i < HIDDEN_NEURONS; i++) {
    ErrorTotal = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < OUTPUT_NEURONS; k++) {
        DeltaETotalOut = -(Target[k] - Network.OLayer.Cell[k].Output);
        DeltaOutNet = ActivateSigmoidPrime(Network.OLayer.Cell[k].Output);
        DeltaErrorNet = DeltaETotalOut * DeltaOutNet;
        Error = DeltaErrorNet * Network.OLayer.Cell[k].Weight[i];
        ErrorTotal += Error;
    }

    DeltaOutNet = ActivateSigmoidPrime(Network.HLayer.Cell[i].Output); 
    for (int j = 0; j < INPUT_NEURONS; j++) {
        DeltaETotalWeight = ErrorTotal * DeltaOutNet*Network.ILayer.Image[j];
        Network.HLayer.Cell[i].Weight[j] -= 0.5 * DeltaETotalWeight;
    }
}

//Update Weights
_indexOutput = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < OUTPUT_NEURONS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < HIDDEN_NEURONS; j++) {
        Network.OLayer.Cell[i].Weight[j] = OutputUpdatedWeights[_indexOutput];
        _indexOutput++;
    }
}}
```

How can I solve this issue? 
I didn't worked on the hidden layer nor biases, is it due to it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, since Backpropagation is notoriously hard to implement and especially to debug (I guess everyone who did it can relate) it’s much harder to debug some Code written by others.

After a quick view over your code, I’m quite surprised that you calculate a negative delta term? Are you using ReLU or any sigmoid function? I’m quite sure there is more. But I’d suggest you to stay away from MNIST until you got your network to solve XOR.

I’ve wrote a summary in pseudo code on how to implement Backpropagation in pseudo code. I’m sure you’ll be able to translate it into C++ quite easily.

[Strange convergence in simple Neural Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741187/strange-convergence-in-simple-neural-network/47747169#47747169)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience neural networks should really be implemented with matrix operations. This will make your code faster and easier to debug.

The way to debug backpropagation is to use finite difference. For a loss function `J(theta)` we can approximate the gradient in each dimension with `(J(theta + epsilon*d) - J(theta))/epsilon` with `d` a one-hot vector representing one dimension (note the similarity to a derivative).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method